# Where other than under "email settings" and "my logins" in my profile do I need to update my e-mail address?

Tags: support, email-addresses

I just noticed (on a site I am a moderator on) that in my profile, under Activity > Account info (visible only to moderators), "email" shows an e-mail address that I no longer use for Stack Exchange.

I have already (quite a while ago now) changed the e-mail address under *Edit profile and settings* > *Edit email settings*, as well as under *Edit profile and settings* > *My logins*. I have also verified today that those two pages show the correct e-mail address.

I am *almost certain* that I did the corresponding changes throughout the network when I updated the e-mail address. I certainly did not deliberately leave the old e-mail address anywhere that I was aware of.

**In what locations other than those two do I need to update my e-mail address for the change to apply everywhere, network-wide?** Alternatively, from which user-editable field does the "email" field of the Account info mod view get its data?

Comment: I think it's the email used for registration (check if it's the same on PII). Speculation: it might also be a remnant from using OpenID back then when it's still supported.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. *"check if it's the same on PII"* Yep, it is. That still leaves the question of how to change it. As for OpenID, I specifically deleted that login method way back when; the only login method listed now is the e-mail address I want to use.

Comment: If it's under PII, then I'm more confident to say that it's used only when registering a SE account for the first time, so I don't think it can be changed since it's also for moderation purpose (note: clicking the email on the PII section reveals something more).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. That would appear to be in direct contradiction to [the GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=EN) (and [SE has specifically said that they consider the GDPR a *good* thing](/q/310321/157730)), Section 3, Article 16, *Right to rectification*, as well as *at best* potentially useless for moderation purposes (an outdated e-mail address is potentially *worse* than useless, since there is no reason to believe that even if it was accurate and monitored when the account was created, it necessarily still is either).

Comment: I have [made a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-originally-registered-email-address-may-be-retained-in-the-system-even) asking for this info to be removed from all sites.

Answer (score 5):

This is a vestigial field; it's still used for unregistered users, Gravatar, and maybe a few other things I forget... But it's no longer directly editable except on Area51.

If you need / want to clear it, you can [contact support](/contact) and we'll get you taken care of.

I've cleared all of these emails from your account, with the exception of Area51 - you can do that yourself: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/edit/68299 (since you probably want to *change* it there, not clear it). (Other users will need to edit that URL to use their own Area 51 user ID instead.)

Comment: I've asked [a question about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-originally-registered-email-address-may-be-retained-in-the-system-even).